# Salesforce Web Service Execution

Tags: rest-api, webservices

There is a requirement wherein, I need to have a connection established between Salesforce and  AS400. The AS400 developers will be providing us with web services and similarly, I need to provide web services (RESTful) to them to have the connection built.

Me being new to web service, I am little confused about where to start in order to execute Salesforce web services (RESTful).

Could anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: Study their Documentation regarding Web services .

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST) tutorial by Salesforce evangelist [Josh Birk](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/41/joshbirk) is a good starting point to create Apex RESTful services. If you are not familiar with Force.com REST API, read [this](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_REST_API) first. They key steps are

A) Declare a REST endpoint by annotating a global class with “@RestResource” and define the name of the endpoint. e.g.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/MyEndPoint/*')
global with sharing class RESTCaseController {
```

B) Define appropriate handling for GET, POST or other requests depending on which type of requests you want to serve (examples given in quoted links)

BTW, I am not sure why you'd need to have web services on both Salesforce and AS400 sides to interact.

Here's another helpful [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_3Rcfkt13Bw) on creating an Apex RESTful web service.

Comment: The reason for having services on both the ends is to have the accounts, contacts synchronized at any given instance. Like if they make any change in Salesforce, these changes need to be reflected in AS400 and vice verse. 

One quick question, is there a way where I can execute the web service as a command line or in a URL by passing header parameters.

Comment: Fair enough - the explanation for having web services at both ends sounds reasonable. Yes, you could fire your GET/ POST requests as CURLs with appropriate URL and params set accordingly. Here's a helpful blog post form avidev on using CURL for RESTful Apex web services - http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2013/09/salesforce-rest-webservices-part-i.html There's also the force.com CLI but I am NOT sure if it supports invoking invoking RESTful Apex services.

Comment: BTW, if you found the answer helpful, please mark it as 'Accepted' for everybody's benefit.

Comment: Thnx Gaurav, the blog you've suggested was bit helpful, as I could run the cURL command line. However, I am in still need of knowing how to execute the web service as a URL(passing header parameters) rather than cURL command line. I would like to give this URL to other other party for them to parse the JSON output and insert/update the result into AS400.

Comment: The quoted tutorial gives an example of a URL which shows you accept request parameters in the URL - https://na8.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FieldCase?companyName=GenePoint Here companyName is a parameter and the passed value is 'GenePoint'. Just to clarify, CURLs are just a way of hitting the web service URL for testing and the other party would normally programatically generate a GET (or POST as applicable) request to your web service and your RESTful web service will return the appropriate JSON data to them in the response. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I'm bit confused with what you're trying to explain. Just to clarify, isn't there a way to call/run a web service via a URL link other than running a cURL command line. When the above link [ap1.salesforce.com..](https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/FieldCase?companyName=GenePoint) is opened, it says that "INVALID_SESSION_ID". So, how can I pass the session id along with the company name or some other parameter.

Comment: There are several ways to call/ run a web service to TEST it - you could use tools such as POSTMan, Advanced Rest client in Chrome etc. The quoted link will obviously return an error because it requires authentication first. When you are building this request programatically, you will be setting the required auth params. This is a general principle of RESTful architecture. I strongly encourage you read about RESTful architecture first.

Comment: Like what would I need to provide the other party to run/call the web service. 

I have got the idea on creating web service class but unable to guide to external application developer on this.

Comment: There are several tutorials for that. One of them is http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Consuming_Force.com_SOAP_and_REST_Web_Services_from_.NET_Applications I hope this helps.